# mouse.up() not working after mouse.move()

Tags: python, mouseevent, playwright, mouseup

I'm writing a test in Playwright Python and pytest to see if the auto mouse movements can be simulated to look more like of a real user's. I use a local html canvas written from html and javascript, the code is from [here](https://www.onlywebpro.com/2013/01/10/create-html5-canvas-drawing-board-within-5-minutes/). **The mouse is supposed to move to point (400,50) in the browser before the HTML canvas file is requested** (In the real function, the starting point will instead will randomized. Otherwise, it will always start at (0,0) which would make it look more like a bot). **When the canvas is open, it's supposed to draw lines from left to right using [WindMouse algorithm](https://ben.land/post/2021/04/25/windmouse-human-mouse-movement/) with the same x-values for start and end points, respectively. There shouldn't be any lines connected between the lines, except for the one from the starting point to the first line.** This should be because after initiating to hold down the mouse's left button with `page.mouse.down()`, and then actually drawing with `page.mouse.move()` from `x=100` to `x=1200` with different y-values in range 100 to 1000, the mouse should release outside of the loop with `page.mouse.up()`.

As seen in the image below, that's not what happened. Instead the **`page.mouse.up()` doesn't seem to execute after `page.mouse.down()` and `page.mouse.move()`**. I have researched and found that it might be because when the mouse left button has been held down for a certain amount of time, the browser will recognize the action as a mouse drag instead. If this is the case, how do you disable the browser's ability to automatically switch mouse action recognition; in this case, it would be to disable it from automatically recognizing `page.mouse.down()` and `page.mouse.move()` after a certain amount of time as a mouse drag? And if this is not the case, **how do you fix this problem with Playwright `page.mouse.up()`?**
[image]

Please have a look at the code:

```
def test_drawing_board():
    rel_path = r"/mats/drawing_board.html"
    file_path = "".join([r"file://", os.getcwd(), rel_path])
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        # Fetch drawing board
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=0.1)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.mouse.move(400,50) # Place mouse in a random position in the browser before fetching the page
        page.goto(file_path)

        #Move mouse
        start_point = 100
        x = 1200
        for y in range(100, 1000, 100):
            # Generate mouse points
            points = []
            wm(start_point, y, x, y, M_0=15, D_0=12, move_mouse=lambda x, y: points.append([x, y]))

            # Draw
            page.mouse.down()
            for point in points:
                page.mouse.move(point[0], point[1])
            page.mouse.up()
```

Comment: Why is the mouse down event also in the points loop?

Comment: You're right, I have now put `page.mouse.down()` outside of the loop as edited but it still didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `# Draw block` it should include a `page.mouse.move(start_point, y)` to move to the beginning of the line before every draw as @tomgalfin suggested, and then `page.mouse.down()`. To test out if before drawing the first line, the mouse was in a specific position even before requesting the page. I wanted to confirm the initial mouse position with a line drawn between it and the first line's beginning position. This is achieved with adding a `page.mouse.down()` before the `# Move mouse` loop as edited. Here's the solved code and the results

```
def test_drawing_board():
    rel_path = r"/mats/drawing_board.html"
    file_path = "".join([r"file://", os.getcwd(), rel_path])
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        # Fetch drawing board
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=0.1)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.mouse.move(400,50) # Place mouse in a random position in the browser before fetching the page
        page.goto(file_path)

        # Start points
        start_point = 100
        x = 1200

        # Move mouse
        page.mouse.down()
        for y in range(100, 1000, 100):
            # Generate mouse points
            points = []
            wm(start_point, y, x, y, M_0=15, D_0=12, move_mouse=lambda x, y: points.append([x, y]))

            # Draw
            page.mouse.move(start_point, y)
            page.mouse.down()
            for point in points:
                page.mouse.move(point[0], point[1])
            page.mouse.up()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each iteration of "y" you issue a mouse up event. However, you dont issue a mouse move event to the start of the new line before putting the mouse down again.

Try the below code:

```
    for y in range(100, 1000, 100):
        # Generate mouse points
        points = []
        wm(start_point, y, x, y, M_0=15, D_0=12, move_mouse=lambda x, y: points.append([x, y]))

        page.mouse.up()
        # Move mouse to start of new line
        page.mouse.move(points[0][0], points[0][1])
        # Mouse back down
        page.mouse.down()
        #Iterate the remaining points
        for point in points[1:]:
            page.mouse.move(point[0], point[1])
        page.mouse.up()
```

Comment: It's still the same

Comment: Try adding a mouse up event before the first move